# code for converting GMT to device time zone not working

Tags: java, android, calendar, timezone

I have a time input in the following format from a RSS feed:

**Wed Jun 13 17:05:44 +0000 2012**

and I need output as **Wed Jun 13, 2012 22:35:44**

The source time will be always in GMT, and the required output time will be in the device time zone(it may be GMT+5:30 or GMT-2:00 or any).

So firstly I have an calendar instance with GMT, as follows.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

Then modified the calendar like following using StringTokenizer on input time.

```
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, date);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
.
.
etc.
```

Next I have the following code:

```
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
```

Basically the above code changes a calendar into device time zone.
Now the matter is the above code is *working fine in normal environment, but not working in Android*.
Any solution? Please help.

Comment: Just curious - what time-zone is 5 hours 30 minutes from GMT?

Comment: The input time zone is GMT. Output time is based on user. If the user in India then its GMT+5:30 if in Pakistan then GMT+5:00 and so on. please check the code "calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());" which is working as normal java project but not as android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you required [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse string value in [Date](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html) object and then you can set Timezone in Date as well as you can make [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) object with help of Date that calendar object will be your device timezone instance.

Below code is working at my side

```
    String input_format = "EEE MMMMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy";
    String input_value="Wed Jun 13 17:05:44 +0000 2012";
    Date date=null;

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(input_format);
    try {
        date = sdf.parse(input_value);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Calendar calendar = sdf.getCalendar();
    calendar.setTime(date);
```

Comment: Yes.. its working & working perfectly.Not only in IST(GMT+5:30) but in all time zones. Thanks..

Answer (score -1):

if i understand it right, you just want to set the timezome

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setTimeZone("Europe/Paris");
```

this for example set the timezone to Paris

Comment: Thanks friend, here you used "Europe/Paris" as new time zone. But in my app I don't know about the users time zone. i.e. the output time may vary based on different users.

Comment: okay i understood, im not sure but maybe this link can help you http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html

Comment: I already checked that but there is no such method to convert the time zone.