# DateFormat does not get changed when change locale

Tags: android, localization

I am using this code to format the date according to phone locale

```
private String localisedDate(String date) {

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    try{
    Date d1 = df.parse(date);
    Locale myLocale = Locale.getDefault();
    DateFormat sdf = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, myLocale);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    FieldPosition fp = new FieldPosition(DateFormat.YEAR_FIELD);
    sb = sdf.format(d1, sb, fp);
    sb.replace(sb.lastIndexOf("/") ,sb.length(), new SimpleDateFormat("/yyyy").format(d1) );
    Log.e("date",sb.toString());
    return sb.toString();
}catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    return date;
}
}
```

This code shows perfect behavior on emulator and on galaxy tab p1000(froyo) 
But on htc and experia no matter which locale selected shows single format only

i.e. dd/MM/yyyy
is there any thing else i need to check for locale while on smartphone?
please provide some help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You may check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201793/code-for-converting-gmt-to-device-time-zone-not-working) link, probably you may get some idea from here.

After the code

`calendar.setTime(date);`

just convert `calendar` to String.